# Apply background color/image to span using CSS

Tags: css

I have below kind of HTML structure and want to apply CSS on span using CSS only.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <img src="/test/test.png">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  <input type="hidden">
<span>
</span>
<span>
</span>
</td>

</tr>
</table>

I am trying below CSS but it is not applying any color.

img[src *="/test/test.png"] +span {
background-color:Red;

}
```

I want to apply background color/image to first span only with the help of specific image tag.

Comment: Can you refine your question a little bit. Does the styling you what to give the span depend on the image. If not you can select the span with,  `td span { }`

Comment: It is depend on image only, because same html structure available on page multiple times and i want to apply css in themes so accross all application it will apply.

Comment: You can use nth child like so `td:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
}` if you want the first span,  or (4) of you want the second span. But you can select the span with the image in CSS

Comment: But how can i select span depend upon image url. if i apply nth child for td, it will apply to others td as well on page with same structure. I want to apply to specific span which bound with particular image only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hope this will work for you

```css
td img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 600px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

span:nth-child(3)  {
    border: 5px solid;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f00;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
  display:inline-block;
    background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/W2tYdfv/88.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <img src="https://i.ibb.co/k8N4R4Z/66.jpg">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  <input type="hidden">
<span>
</span>
<span>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In your above example if i apply css on span nth child element, CSS will apply to all span nth child(3) element on the page. I need to apply only span below to that perticular image having scr=test.png